# For SVN/Tortoisesvn, how to show log for only folder properties, ie not contents of folder as well?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have an SVN repo with TortoiseSvn and VisualSvn running on top of them (VisualSvn providing the server and the VS2008 client).
We have been using some of the folder properties and now I have an issue where one folder, that contains a ton of stuff with lots of checkins, has properties that were changed somewhere.

What is the easiest way for me to do some kind of SVN show log to find out the history of folder properties' changes?
We're open to other tools as well since merging (even using WinMerge) is not appropriate. (Eventually on that side I'm considering a recommendation to GIT.)
thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about (for unix):

`find . -name .svn -prune -o -type d -exec svn_cmd {} \;`

Of course, you will want to modify the part that says `svn_cmd` to be whatever svn command you want to use to have the output as you want it. Perhaps, [this book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.html) will be helpful for that. From glancing at it briefly they mention `svn proplist`.

`find . -name .svn -prune -o -type d -exec svn proplist {} \;`

Comment: @YGomez, thank you for such a quick reply! I admit I am still confused on windows' find syntax. I got an error;

Comment: src>find . -name .svn -prune -o type d -exec svn proplist {} \;
FIND: Parameter format not correct

Comment: (SO-TIP: Comments don't allow one to type CR's in them...)

Comment: I think I need to use "svn log myfolder -v" which will show all commits and all the path/info changes for the command. (svn proplist myfoldername -v will show folder properties details for an item.) But I don't know what the {} \ are in the find command; are they the arglist things?

Comment: @Eli AnneTheAgile: Yup, sorry I meant Unix, should have specified. I didn't know windows had a find command.

Comment: Rats, yes, my problem is on windows. Maybe I need to install the nix toolkit.

Comment: Even though I need a Windows fix, I want to credit Yarian, so marked as answer. Thank you!